# How to run Xcode 10.2 Simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode10.2

Overnight my Xcode has update to **10.2** and ever since I can't run the simulator anymore. Affected seems **every Simulator** regardless of Model or iOS Version.

Xcode is building and showing "Running  on iPhone X", but I can't see a simulator.

[image]

I have the Simulator Icon in the Dock, but clicking on it leads to Xcode.

[image]

"Show all Windows" on the Icon just brings me "No Available Windows" on my Screens.

I have restarted Xcode and iMac. Help is very appreciated.

Comment: I have tried: Delete Derived Data, Clean, Clean Build Folder, Restarts. Different Simulators and different iOS Versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Simulators and Devices window, select each simulator in turn and delete it until there are no simulators. Quit Xcode. Restart the computer. Now create a simulator and build and run to it.

Comment: That did it. Very annoying tho. But thank you for helping out!

Comment: I find I have to do that after every Xcode update. So now it’s second nature.

Comment: Then I guess I can call myself lucky that I never had to do that. Bummer was just that the transition to Swift 5 was super smooth and then it still took me hours due to this challenge... Any-who. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Simulator Icon in the Dock and click Show, It might be hidden for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on the app in the dock, and click `Show`.
2. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> and click `Quit`, then relaunch the simulator again.